# how do I connect sys.argv into my float value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I must use "q" (which is a degree measure) from the command line and then convert "q" to radians and have it write out the value of sin(5q) + sin(6q). Considering that I believe I have to use sys.argv's for this I have no clue where to even begin

Comment: You can start by wrapping your algorithm inside a python **function**, then post your function, your expected input/output here so that more people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following commands
`q=sys.argv[1] #you can give the decimal value too in your command line`
now q will be string eg. "1.345" so you have convert this to float[ using
function `q=float(q)` .